# Change the password Instruction Content in Dynamically based input in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6lOz.png)

When the user give the upper case remove the uppercase word in the instruction and when the special characters is given remove spl characters...,and when the field is empty show the old instruction.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, there are already few packages exist for this. Try https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/password-strength/home OR similar packages.

Comment: @SanthoshV This question has very little to do with "Reinventing the Wheel" and the suggestion to include another dependency for something that Angular can do perfectly fine on its own with little effort is just a bad advice.

Comment: @ak.leimrey Someone had already did that "little effort" and published that small package. Even if you do code, again it will be same as that package. It's nothing wrong, if that guy tried some 50%, and seeking help to complete. His question looks like, he want someone to code for himself, he didn't post whatever he tried. So I suggested that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="password" (keyup)="error_message()" value='user_password'/> 
    <label>{{instruction}}</label> 
 error_message()
    {
        if(this.user_password=="")
        {
            this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Numbers,Uppercase,Spl Characters";
        }
        else
        {
            const regx              = new RegExp("(?=.*?[A-Z])");
            const Regx_speChar      = new RegExp("(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])");
            const Regx_number       = new RegExp("(?=.*?[0-9])");

            const password_caps     = this.user_password.match(regx)?true:false;
            const password_splcase  = this.user_password.match(Regx_speChar)?true:false;
            const password_numbers  = this.user_password.match(Regx_number)?true:false;

            if( password_caps!=true && password_splcase!=true && password_numbers!=true)
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Numbers,Uppercase,Spl Characters";
            }
            else if( password_caps==true && password_splcase !=true && password_numbers !=true )
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Numbers,Spl Characters";
            }
            else if( password_caps!=true && password_splcase==true && password_numbers !=true)
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Numbers,Uppercase";
            }
            else if( password_caps!=true && password_splcase!=true && password_numbers==true )  
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Uppercase,Spl Characters";
            }
            else if( password_caps==true && password_splcase==true && password_numbers!=true )
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Numbers";
            }
            else if( password_caps==true && password_splcase !=true && password_numbers==true )
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Spl Characters";
            }   
            else if( password_caps!=true && password_splcase==true && password_numbers==true )
            {
                this.instruction = "Password Need 6-13 Characters With Uppercase";
            }   
            else if( password_caps==true && password_splcase==true && password_numbers==true )
            {
                this.instruction = "";
            }
        }
```